# Difference between the use of withObject:self and withObject:nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, performselector

I have been wondering about the following lines of code

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

1. Whats the difference between the above 2 lines of code.
2. When should we set object as `nil` and when should we set object as `self`?

In most cases I have noticed the object to be set as `nil`.

Comment: read documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I have read the document. I have tried both lines code in same context and it worked. So wanted to know the difference, which I couldn't find googling.

Comment: - (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay  

 anArgument: The argument to pass to the method when it is invoked. Pass
 nil if the method does not take an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is whether or not you are passing an object to the selector. All the selector is doing is describing a method.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

is different from:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod:usingThis:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

Now if you want the selector (i.e. method) to work on some object that you pass in, say an Array, Dictionary, or class. You use withObject. As in:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:myDictionary afterDelay:1.0];

-(void)myMethod:(NSDictionary*)dictionary
{
// Do something with object
}
```

You could pass in anything including a reference to the current class (e.g. self), as you did in your example.

Answer (score 8):

In the example you listed you won't experience any different behavior because your method `myMethod` takes no arguments. Where this is useful, is when you have a method that takes arguments.

Let's say we declared a method, `squareRootMethod:` that takes a NSNumber and returns the squareRoot. Then you would call `[self performSelector:@selector(squareRootMethod:) withObject:numberToRoot afterDelay:1.0]`

There are also methods like `performSelector:withObject:withObject:` for selectors that take more than one argument.

Comment: `withObject:withObject`?  May I see some documentation, sir?

Comment: [performSelector:withObject:withObject:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCGGCBE)

Comment: But there is no method that has withObject:withObject: with delay

Answer (score 3):

Notice the difference between these two:

```
@selector(myMethod)
@selector(myMethod:)
```

The first one is a method that doesn't take any parameters, the second is a method that takes one parameter. The `withObject:` part of the `performSelector:` method you're using allows you to pass an object into the method when it is called. However, in the case where the method doesn't take any parameters it doesn't matter because it won't be used.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you passed self as the argument to pass to the method when it is invoked.  But your method takes no arguments, so it is unnecessary fluff.

In the second example, you passed `nil`, so the method is passed `nil` to it's non-existent arguments and then terminates.  This is more "efficient" in the sense that because your method takes no arguments, and `nil. Is the object equivalent of NULL, then you pass less fluff through that is ignored anyhow.

Comment: Quoi?  What do you mean the method doesn't take an argument?  I can send nil to any method I please.

Comment: thats what i meant if u pass nil then method doesnot have any argument if u pass value it has argument which u can use it

Comment: No, that's exactly what I argued against.  I can send nil to a method with a million arguments whenever I please.

Comment: have u read question he said whats the difference. I meant what he wants

Comment: Your wording is weird.  Here, let me fix it.  I'll revoke my downvote.